# Can't see "Must implement" error

Tags: vb.net

I need another (dozen) pair of eyes on this. The following code:

```
Interface iRuleEntity
    Function GetRuleViolations() As List(Of RuleViolation)
End Interface

Partial Public Class Feedback
    Implements iRuleEntity

    Public Function GetRuleViolations() As List(Of RuleViolation)
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

is giving me this error:

```
'Feedback' must implement 'Function GetRuleViolations() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of RuleViolation)' for interface 'iRuleEntity'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are all your namespaces right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't said that `GetRuleViolations` implements `iRuleEntity.GetRuleViolations`. It's not implicit like it is in C#.

From the [docs for `Implements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcb9373h.aspx):

> You use the Implements statement to
>   specify that a class or structure
>   implements one or more interfaces, and
>   then for each member you use the
>   Implements keyword to specify which
>   interface and which member it
>   implements.

So:

```
Partial Public Class Feedback
    Implements iRuleEntity

    Public Function GetRuleViolations() As List(Of RuleViolation) _
    Implements iRuleEntity.GetRuleViolations
        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

(Note the line continuation on the first line of the function.)

Answer (score 3):

```
Partial Public Class Feedback
    Implements iRuleEntity

    Public Function GetRuleViolations() As List(Of RuleViolation)
        Implements iRuleEntity.GetRuleViolations

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```